# Dynamic resultset with dapper on 3.5

Tags: c#-3.0, dapper, micro-orm

I've got a store procedure call returning a recordset whith field unknown in advance. For some interop reason I need to make it working on 3.5, so I don't have any dynamic support. 
Is there some built-in solution in dapper? I did not find any by myself.
If there is no such a solution, does it make sense ( and does it work ) to create on the fly a type exposing the property I would fetch ?
**EDIT**
I managed to add a completely external solution ( without tweaking the original codebase ) by creating a dynamic object in c# 3.0. 
[Here is the extension dapper code](https://github.com/FelicePollano/Dapper.Toolkit/blob/master/Dapper.Toolkit/Dapper/Extensions.cs)
[and here the factory for the dynamic object](https://github.com/FelicePollano/Dapper.Toolkit/blob/master/Dapper.Toolkit/PropertyBag/PropertyBagFactory.cs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, *actually* the `dynamic` support in dapper is implemented via ExpandoObject, which is *basically* just a dictionary. It would be pretty simple to tweak the existing code to return `IDictionary<string,object>` instead of `dynamic` in the case of 3.5

Comment: agree, but suppose I don't want to touch the code, what about the idea I proposed?

Comment: @FelicePollano I really don't want to go the `TypeBuilder` route just for that. What is the use-case here? What are you looking to do with these objects? UI data-binding? (taking a wild stab here, based on your leaning towards strong types)

Comment: use case is a little c**p, is calling an SP and selecting a field from the result. Both the SP to call and the field to select come from another query. I agree it would be nice IDictionary<> but I prefer not have to deal with a modified dapper codebase...